# Immediate disconnection of mongo connection (smoke test)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, ecmascript-6, node-modules, node-mongodb-native

I'm running some connection diagnostics to mongo atlas without running any db operations. How to disconnect gracefully?

```
// connect
import connect from "mongodb"
const clientPromise =  connect(
  mongoUrl,{useUnifiedTopology,useNewUrlParser}
)
const client = await clientPromise

// TO-DO: disconnect

/** ... */
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work:

```
// connect
import connect, close from "mongodb"
const clientPromise =  connect(
  mongoUrl,{useUnifiedTopology,useNewUrlParser}
)
const client = await clientPromise

// TO-DO: disconnect

close();
```